# Solr and operation on tokens

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to use whitespace tokeniser on field keywords.
my sample date is

```
doc 1:{location:"Pune",keywords:samsung 3.0MP Black}
doc 2:{location:"Mumbai",keywords:sony 4.0MP Black}
```

I am trying to avoid seprate fields insted I indexed all keywords in same field.

1. can we perform and operation on tokens e.g. `black and 4.0mp`
2. Is it feasible solution rather than creating seprate field?

Answer (score 0):

Either you use "q.op = "OR" operator in your query to search with "black 4.0mp" it will internally converts it to keywords="black" OR keywords="4.0mp" else you can use "AND" which works for keywords="black" AND keywords="4.0mp"

I think this will work for you...